# Power of Cosine Inequality

Tags: real-analysis

The problem is such:

> Show that $$\cos{px}\ge \cos^p{x}$$ given that $0\le x\le \pi/2$ and $0<p<1$

I'm pretty sure this is straight forward given the sum formula for cosine...

$$\cos{px}=\cos{[(p-1)x+x]}=\cos{[(p-1)x]}\cos{x}-\sin{[(p-1)x]}\sin{x}$$

Since $\sin{[(p-1)x]}<0$, then

$$\cos{px}=\cos{[(p-1)x]}\cos{x}+\sin{[(1-p)x]}\sin{x}\ge\cos{[(p-1)x]}\cos{x}$$

So if i do this $p-1$ more times I will end up with

$$\cos{px}\ge \cos{[(p-p)x]}\cos^p{x}=\cos^p{x}$$

My question, is there a better way to do this?  Not that it is not good, but I was wondering if there were more indirect approaches or other more subtle ways.  I was thinking DeMoivre, but was trying to stay within the Real realm and not delve into the Complex system.

Comment: given that ... "and o" what do you mean by "and o". Something missing ?

Comment: Yeah, sorry my formatting was off..forgot a couple of dollar signs.

Comment: Are you sure your prove doesn't assume $p$ is a positive integer?

Comment: `if i do this p−1 more times` But the problem says that `0 < p < 1`.

Comment: Oh yeah.... No, the problem is explicitly stated that $0<p<1$.  I don't know why my head went with $p$ is an integer.  So I need to rework my proof.

Comment: So what approach do I have to go through to show this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the interval $\bigl[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\bigr]$, $\cos$ is concave, hence

$$\cos (px) = \cos \bigl( p x + (1-p)\cdot 0\bigr) \geqslant p\cos x + (1-p)\cos 0 = 1 - p(1 - \cos x)$$

for $0 \leqslant x \leqslant \frac{\pi}{2}$.

The function $t \mapsto t^{1/p}$ is convex on $[0,+\infty)$, therefore $(1 + y)^{1/p} \geqslant 1 + \frac{1}{p}y$ for $y \geqslant -1$. Together with the monotonicity of $t \mapsto t^{1/p}$, these facts yield

$$\bigl(\cos (px)\bigr)^{1/p} \geqslant \bigl(1 - p(1 - \cos x)\bigr)^{1/p} \geqslant 1 - \frac{p(1-\cos x)}{p} = \cos x,$$

from which the assertion follows.

Comment: [+1] for a nice proof. I have also given a proof based on increasing properties of certain functions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof of

$$\tag{1}\cos(px) \geq (\cos(x))^p$$

that is different from the proof by Daniel Fisher.

Let $p \in (0,1)$. Let us exclude at first $x=\pi/2$, a value for which (1) is evidently true. Thus we will work with $x \in [0,\pi/2).$

Natural logarithm $\ln$ being a bijective continuous increasing function, (1) is equivalent to:

$$\ln(\cos(px)) \geq p \ln(\cos(x))$$

Let $\varphi$ be defined by $\varphi(x):=\ln(\cos(px))-p \ln(x)$.

Thus, we have to prove that $\forall x  \in (0,\pi/2)$, we have $\varphi(x) \geq 0$. As $\varphi(0)=0$, it suffices to prove that $\forall x  \in [0,\pi/2), \varphi'(x) \geq 0$.

This is easy because

$$\varphi'(x)=-p\dfrac{\sin(px)}{\cos(px)}+p\dfrac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}=p(\tan(x)- \tan(px)).$$

Otherwise said, it remains to prove that, for $x \in [0,\pi/2)$,

$$\tag{2}\tan(x)\geq \tan(px)$$

(2) is an immediate consequence of the fact that, for $p \leq 1$, $x>px$ and that the restriction of $\tan$ on $[0,\pi/2)$ is a continuous increasing function.

Remark: Here is a graphical representation of functions

$$f(x)=\cos(px)$ and $g(x)=(\cos(x))^p$ for $p=0.3.$$

The curve of $g$ is somewhat surprising...

[image]